# Is it possible to display some products dimensions by yards instead of inches

Tags: magento2, product, dimensions

I have some products measured in inches, and some in yards. When I go to list a simple product, the only option that I have is inches.

Is there a straightforward way to make the switch, or do I have to write custom code to turn the grayed out "in" into a dropdown with options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the Magento default from Inches, so we got around this by adding an attribute for yards.